# Is there any limit on ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION on Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, partitioning, amazon-athena

I am running a query similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD IF NOT EXISTS
PARTITION (date = 'a', hour = '00')
PARTITION (date = 'b', hour = '01')
PARTITION (date = 'c', hour = '02')
PARTITION (date = 'd', hour = '03')
.
.
.
.
.//around 1000 partitions
PARTITION (date = 'aa', hour = '05')
PARTITION (date = 'bb', hour = '06')
PARTITION (date = 'cc', hour = '07')
PARTITION (date = 'dd', hour = '08')
```

The query is not throwing any error but it is not loading partitions on the Athena table. When I break the query to 500 partitions. It seems to work. Is there any limit on the number of partitions on the  ADD PARTITION command? I went with the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` instead of this. Just curious about why the query didn't run, I couldn't find any limit in the Athena documentation.